# React - Can console log object, but not specific property of said object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing an exercise to learn React in which I have set up a page with a list of clickable pokemon names which are linking to the pokemons specific detail page. Below is the code of the details page

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function DetailsPage() {
  const pokeName = useParams();
  console.log(pokeName);
  const [pokeList, setPokeList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      setPokeList(response.data.results);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const specificPokemon = pokeList.find((pokemon) => {
    return pokemon.name === pokeName.pokemon_name;
  });

  console.log(specificPokemon);
  console.log(specificPokemon.name);

return <div><p>{specificPokemon.name}</p></div>;
}
```

This code has an error I fail to understand

The `console.log(specificPokemon)` works fine, but the `console.log(specificPokemon.name)` gives me the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

The correct code is the following, but I wonder why my method doesn't work

```
  const [pokeList2, setPokeList2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeName.pokemon_name}`
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      setPokeList(response.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(pokeList);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component is mounted, pokeList is an empty array.

React will run the following block **before** the useEffect hook has finished running:

```js
const specificPokemon = pokeList.find((pokemon) => {
  return pokemon.name === pokeName.pokemon_name;
});

console.log(specificPokemon);
console.log(specificPokemon.name);
```

As long as your array is empty, `specificPokemon` will be `undefined` and calling `specificPokemon.name` will trigger your error.

Beware with `console.log`, its behavior is not always synchronous.
You might think `specificPokemon` is properly defined because `console.log` won't necessarily show `undefined`.
To verify this, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(specificPokemon));`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `console.log(specificPokemon)` will give _undefined_ at first but later updates itself? If so, why doesn't this happen for `console.log(specificPokemon.name)`

Comment: That's right, and it doesn't happen with `specificPokemon.name` because accessing the `name` property forces immediate resolution of the log call

Answer (score 1):

When the code runs first the `pokeList` is an empty array and it cannot find the property `name`. You should create a second state and do something like this

```
 const pokeName = useParams();
 const [pokeList, setPokeList] = useState([]);
 const [specificPokemon, setSpecificPokemon] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
   );
   setPokeList(response.data.results);

   const selectedPokemon = response.data.results.find((pokemon) => {
      return pokemon.name === pokeName.pokemon_name;
   });

   setSpecificPokemon(selectedPokemon)
  };

  fetchData();
  }, [])
```

And don't forget to make the specificPokemon property optional like this `specificPokemon?.name`